# My greeting, Some problems with react routing when project hosted

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I created react dom routing in my react app. Component navigation works if you run npm start, but if the project is built and hosted, a 404 error occurs during navigation This happens because the hosting requests index.html when the react changes the main html file to (page name) .html during navigation.

Comment: yes, you need to handle that as React is a SPA. you need to make some changes in your server configuration whichever server you are using.

Comment: How can i fix this?

Comment: which server are you using?